# how do I use angularJS to display dynamic menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular, for the page below I'm using ngRoute for the menu on the left side. now trying to show selected item in the blue circle area.
HTML code:

```
<nav layout="row" layout-align="start center">
    <a href="#/dashboard">Dashbord</a>
    <a href="{{}}">{{testmenu}}</a>
</nav>
```

What I'm trying to do is binding the "testmenu" with $location.path() in the controller:

```
$scope.testmenu = $location.path().replace('/', '');
```

but when I click different items on the left side menu, "testmenu" doesn't change immediately, it changes only when refreshing the whole page.This is my first question.

---

I'm just using two fixed a elements. there will be more child items, I don't know how do make them more dynamic (for example, the first item is always "dashboard", when I click it, it's child items(like "master" in the picture) should be hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for display data as loop from scope variable.

For example I display menu items using ngRepeat like this way:

**template.html** (template file)

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(name, url) in menuItems"><a href={{url}}>{{name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**mycntrl.js** (controller file)

```
var items = {
    "Deshboard": "http://domain.com/",
    "My Account": "http://domain.com/my-account",
    "My Profile": "http://domain.com/my-profile"
};

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.menuItems = items;
}
```

From above example code display three menu item with link and it's done.

**2.** Raw example for hide show child menu items at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7638/)